# put table side by side with foreach

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, laravel

i need to create labels to print with the information that comes in $ labels. what happens to me is that there is a vertical list, I need them to be 3 horizontally how can I solve?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>Document</title>
<style>
body {
  background: rgb(204,204,204); 
}
page {
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
page[size="A4"] {  
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm; 
}
@media print {
  body, page {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<page size="A4">

@foreach($labels as $label) 

<div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card mb-4">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h6 class="mb-3">REFERÊNCIA: {{$label->ref}}</h6>
                <h6 class="mb-3">TAMANHO: {{$label->size}}</h6>
                <h6 class="mb-3">QUANTIDADE: {{$label->quantity}}</h6>
                <h6 class="mb-3">PRODUTO: {{$label->product}} - {{$label->feature}}</h6>
                <h6 class="mb-3">PARTE: {{$label->part}}</h6>
                <h6 class="mb-3">FINALISTA: {{$label->finalist}}</h6>       
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
@endforeach

</page>

</body>
</html>
```

this page serves to be rendered to pdf with DomPDF

[.card-body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnSZk.png)

[.col-md-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w5kx.png)

Comment: Try adding this to your styles and let me know if it works:  `.col-md-3 {display: inline-block; width: 32%;}`

Comment: didn't work, what can we do more?

Comment: maybe change the `.col-md-3` in my previous response to `.card-body` and see if it works then

Comment: using this option what happens is that I put each <h6> side by side and not the whole

Comment: Can you share some screen shots? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: I edited the post there are the two photos

Comment: how about using a border less table, you can use css to remove the borders

Comment: @Pedro are you sure my first solution didn't work?  I put your code into a test environment and it works just how I thought it would.  See here: https://jsfiddle.net/z2vqwcs6/1/   Do you have anything else which could be effecting the CSS code?